# I cannot send email using smtp in Laravel 5.1.28 ($driver is null in Manager.php)

Tags: email, laravel

I am dealing with a Laravel installation on Ubuntu Server 14.04.

I got this config in mail.php:

```
return [

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    'from' => ['address' => null, 'name' => null],

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    'pretend' => false,

];
```

And this config in .env file:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=***********
DB_USERNAME=*****
DB_PASSWORD=*****
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=foo@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

The error message is this:

```
Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Manager::createDriver(), called in /var/www/****/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Manager.php on line 87 and defined
```

The thing is when I go to Manager.php the variable $driver is null.

```
   /**
     * Create a new driver instance.
     *
     * @param  string  $driver
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     */
    protected function createDriver($driver)
    {
        $method = 'create'.ucfirst($driver).'Driver';

        // We'll check to see if a creator method exists for the given driver. If not we
        // will check for a custom driver creator, which allows developers to create
        // drivers using their own customized driver creator Closure to create it.
        if (isset($this->customCreators[$driver])) {
            return $this->callCustomCreator($driver);
        } elseif (method_exists($this, $method)) {
            return $this->$method();
        }

        throw new InvalidArgumentException("Driver [$driver] not supported.");
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

I don't know why but the code executes 3 times the function `"createDriver($driver) (from Manager.php)"`. Two times with `$driver` to null and one with `$driver` to 'file'. The thing is put .env file and mail.php like says the documentation and forums.

I use send function in this way:

```
    Mail::send('contacta.envio', ['key' => 'value'],
    function($message)
    {
        $message->from('contact@gmail.com');
        $message->to('contact@gmail.com')->subject('contacto');
    });
```

I don't why what is happening here, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is the awnser.

I got config/email.php and the laravel code expect take config from `$app['config']['mail.*'];`

As the email.php is called "email" the config is loaded here `$from = $app['config']['email'];` so the config from .env file is not taken.